# How to list non-empty directories with the command find or ls?

Tags: linux, bash, find, ls

It is necessary to list non-empty directories in a subdirectory
Trying to use

```
find . ! -type d -empty -print
```

but it doesn't work,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're asking for "things that are not directories and are empty", which includes all zero-length files (and would exclude all directories). You want "things that are directories and are not empty", so:

```
find . -type d ! -empty -print
```